# Django skips a url pattern?

Tags: python, django, url

In my urls.py, I have the following:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path('completed/', views.completed, name='completed'),
    path("<single_slug>", views.link_slug, name="link_slug"),
]
```

When I'm testing locally, if I visit IP:8000/completed, it calls the completed() function in my views.py, but when I run it on Heroku (connect to [www.WEBSITE.com/completed](http://www.WEBSITE.com/completed)), it ends up skipping it, passing 'completed' into my link_slug() function.

Here is my views.py:

```py
def completed(request):
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/completed.html',
                  context={'categories':ProjectCategory.objects.all})

def link_slug(request, single_slug):
   #do stuff
```

Comment: You should visit it with `completed/` (with a slash at the end)...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah that works. Strange how it works locally but on in production. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The urls completed/ and completed are different urls you can read about them in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#definitive-urls).